# How to fetch data from a table onto online which a specific id search plsql?

Tags: html, sql, plsql, toad

I have a procedure where users enter "student id" to search and see the details of that individual. I know this inst correct and I have far more syntax to write but so far this is what I have:-

Please note I have declared all variables and my table columns name and types are correct. I haven't ran the code yet because I'm sure I'm missing something more. So please help. I'm coding on toad for oracle in plsql.

Below codes are for fetching the data and putting them onto their specific field online.

```
BEGIN
-- fetching data from table 'unsus' 
    IF EXISTS SELECT UNSUS_STUDENT_NO student_no,
                     UNSUS_STUDENT_NAME name,
                     UNSUS_SUSPEND_ACCOUNT suspend_acc,
                     UNSUS_UNSUSPEND_DATE unsus_date,
                     UNSUS_USER_ID user_id
              FROM   SATURN.UNSUS
              WHERE  UNSUS_SUSPEND_NO = ('000123456');

-- opening table rows (form based)
twbkfrmt.P_TableRowOpen;
twbkfrmt.P_TableData ('Student ID');
twbkfrmt.P_TableData ('Full Name');
twbkfrmt.P_TableData ('Suspended ?');
twbkfrmt.P_TableData ('Unsuspension Date');
twbkfrmt.P_TableData ('Added On ?');
twbkfrmt.P_TableData ('Altered By');
twbkfrmt.P_TableRowOpen;

-- table data adding onto form fields
            twbkfrmt.p_TableDataWhite (HTF.formtext (
                                        cname        => '',
                                        csize        => 25,
                                        cmaxlength   => 9,
                                        cvalue       => student_no,
                                        cattributes  => 'style="font-size:12px" readonly ' || disabled));

            twbkfrmt.p_TableDataWhite (HTF.formtext (
                                        cname        => '',
                                        csize        => 60,
                                        cmaxlength   => 60,
                                        cvalue       => name,
                                        cattributes  => 'style="font-size:12px" readonly ' || disabled));

            twbkfrmt.p_TableDataWhite (HTF.formtext (
                                        cname        => '',
                                        csize        => 15,
                                        cmaxlength   => 5,
                                        cvalue       => suspend_acc,
                                        cattributes  => 'style="font-size:12px" readonly ' || disabled));

            twbkfrmt.p_TableDataWhite (HTF.formtext (
                                        cname        => '',
                                        csize        => 20,
                                        cmaxlength   => 15,
                                        cvalue       => unsus_date,
                                        cattributes  => 'style="font-size:12px" readonly ' || disabled));               

            twbkfrmt.p_TableDataWhite (HTF.formtext (
                                        cname        => '',
                                        csize        => 20,
                                        cmaxlength   => 15,
                                        --cvalue       => ,
                                        cattributes  => 'style="font-size:12px" readonly ' || disabled));       

            twbkfrmt.p_TableDataWhite (HTF.formtext (
                                        cname        => '',
                                        csize        => 30,
                                        cmaxlength   => 30,
                                        cvalue       => user_id,
                                        cattributes  => 'style="font-size:12px" readonly ' || disabled));
```

Comment: There is no `IF EXISTS SELECT` construction in PL/SQL, so I'm not really sure where this is going.

Comment: That's where i was thinking of me going wrong. is it 'Check if Exists' ? but then again do i have to create a function for that too ? if yes, how would i go about doing it ?

Comment: Maybe just populate some variables with a plain [`select into`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/selectinto_statement.htm) and handle `no_data_found` exceptions.

Comment: It's not good practice to rely on exception handling when you can avoid it.

Comment: @Thor I don't see what would be wrong with it here. If you want to display details for a specified id, then `select a, b, c into x, y, z from somewhere where id = p_id` and display the results. If there is no row for the specified ID, either let it fail or else use an exception handler. That's exactly what they are for.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Exception handling are global within the scope of the procedure. It makes extending the procedure more difficult in case OP might need to select again. Exceptions are preferably not to be thrown to begin with. You are also left with more control of the logic flow, you can't return back to the procedure.

Comment: @Thor OK I'm starting to wish I'd never mentioned exception handling. I'm just suggesting that the OP replaces his made-up `if exists` construction with a normal `select into`. The rest of the procedure I leave as an exercise.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson exception handling is an acceptable way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to go about this. The standard method, and it is lightening fast, is to just select the data and have a no_data_found exception. I hope you haven't prefaced all of your column names with the table name, that is not good practice IMHO.

```
DECLARE
    l_student_no        saturn.unsus.student_no%TYPE;
    l_student_name      saturn.unsus.student_name%TYPE;
    l_suspend_account   saturn.unsus.suspend_account%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT student_no, student_name, suspend_account
      INTO l_student_no, l_student_name, l_suspend_account
      FROM saturn.unsus
     WHERE suspend_no = ('000123456');

    -- you have your data, do your HTML formatting.
    twbkfrmt.p_tabledatawhite (
        HTF.formtext (
            cname       => ''
          , csize       => 25
          , cmaxlength  => 9
          , cvalue      => l_student_no
          , cattributes => 'style="font-size:12px" readonly ' || disabled
        )
    );
-- ...
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        -- code jumps to here when the suspend_no is not found
        -- the null means just ignore no_data_found
        NULL;
END;
```

Comment: This looks far more easier syntax than mine. i'll give this a go. i'll let you know if it does what i expected it to. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just need a check whether the set exists.

```
SELECT COUNT(UNSUS_STUDENT_NO) INTO studentCount FROM SATURN.UNSUS
          WHERE  UNSUS_SUSPEND_NO = ('000123456');

IF studentCount > 0 THEN
  -- Insert all logic here.
END IF;
```

Comment: If `all logic here` includes fetching the data from `SATURN.UNSUS` where `UNSUS_SUSPEND_NO = '000123456'`, then you're reading it twice (and hoping nobody deletes it between the count and the processing).

Comment: That's true, without having the opportunity to benchmark this now I'd say the performance is negligible (adding `AND ROWNUM = 1` might shave off ns's) as well as the read/write lock unless OP has very high R/W.

Comment: what my script meant to do is be able to search for the id that user inputs onto the search field. i'm in the middle of creating a checkifexists function for the script. however would or is the script at the top going to do what i'm looking for ?

Comment: As far as I can understand you, yes. Even if you are re-using it a lot I don't see much value in putting it in a function. Still need to store the result in a variable for the comparison. Please remember to select correct answer or post your final solution for prosperity.